# I am defining actionbars in android. How do I add new actions and on click listener to each action?

Tags: android

I am working with action bars for the first time and would like to know for certain examples that show how to add new actions/buttons to the action bar and an intent on each button to load other classes.

A small code snippet with an xml layout would be of much help.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple approach is to use the menu resource and use an showAsAction attribute for each item. Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_check_all"
        android:title="@string/menu_check_all"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_check_all_cond"
        android:icon="@drawable/checked"
        android:visible="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    ></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_uncheck_all"
        android:title="@string/menu_uncheck_all"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_uncheck_all_cond"
        android:icon="@drawable/unchecked"
        android:visible="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    ></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_add_selected_reservations"
        android:title="@string/menu_add_reservations"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_add_reservations_cond"
        android:icon="@drawable/calendar_plus"
        android:visible="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:showAsAction="always"
    ></item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item_open_calendar"
        android:title="@string/menu_open_calendar"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/menu_open_calendar_cond"
        android:icon="@drawable/calendar"
        android:visible="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:showAsAction="never"
    ></item>

</menu>
```

Items which have an "ifRoom" specified are added to the action bar if there is space available. Other possible values are "always" and "never" with the obvious meaning.

This will even work with the compatibility library.

Here is more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: So, when I do this:  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_main_tab, menu);
     Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeActivity.class);
What should I be defining in menu?

Comment: Decide which items to add to always the action bar, which items to add if there is room available, and which items you do not want in the action bar. Then edit user_main_tab.xml by adding the android:showAsAction attribute (see example in my answer).